# Installing "RadeonHD" drivers

Tags: 11.04, drivers, radeon

How do I go about install the "radeonhd" drivers in ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: What card do you have?

Comment: ATI HD 3200 for a laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Additional Drivers` tool (look for it in your dash) or download the ATI drivers from the website and install them with these commands

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs (for amd64) systems
sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-9-x86.x86_64.run (select build deb packages)
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```